# How to take in a time value in payload in hapi?

Tags: joi, hapi, hapi-swagger

I am creating an api using hapi framework and need to take in time as one of the data types in the payload that I receive. I have defined the validation as

```
payload: {
  startTime: Joi.date().timestamp().required(),
  endTime: Joi.date().timestamp().required()
}
```

But when I bring up the swagger documentation page for this validation I see the inputs to be received a below

```
{
  "startTime": 0,
  "endTime": 0
}
```

I was expecting a more user-friendly approach where it would display the timestamp format in swagger like below.

```
{
  "startTime": HH:MM:SS,
  "endTime": HH:MM:SS
}
```

How do I make this possible?

Comment: Going by your validation you're opting to accept timestamps, which are essentially just integers which is why Swagger is defaulting to 0. If you want more explicit timestamps I suggest using `Joi.date().iso()`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried validating it with ```Joi.date().iso()``` but it still shows a number in swagger.

Comment: Now that I checked it again carefully. It definitely works for date and displays ```YYYY-MM-DD``` All I need to do now is to find a way to display the time like this ```2018-11-04T11:59:47Z```